# Sort a deeply nested tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, tuples

I have a list of nested tuples that looks like:

```
l = [('apple', ['gala','fuji', 'macintosh']),
('pear', ['seckel','anjou','bosc'])]
```

And I like to sort the second item of the tuple alphabetically, so that it would look like:

```
l2 = [('apple', ['fuji','gala', 'macintosh']),
('pear', ['anjou','bosc','seckel'])]
```

I know that I could apply `sorted(l)` to it, but I am very new to Python and I am having problems with the iteration. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like the following - using a list comp to build new tuples...

```
l = [('apple', ['gala','fuji', 'macintosh']),
('pear', ['seckel','anjou','bosc'])]

l2 = [(k, sorted(v)) for k, v in l]
# [('apple', ['fuji', 'gala', 'macintosh']), ('pear', ['anjou', 'bosc', 'seckel'])]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can sort "in place" using list.sort().
This approach saves you the assignment, and you don't need to touch the keys.

```
for _,v in l: v.sort()
```

Comment: I'd go so far as not bothering to unpack unnecessarily and just do: `for i in l: i[1].sort()`

Comment: Ouch. I had no idea this would work... it violates the immutability of the tuple, which is weird. A little scary actually. Update: I guess it doesn't matter, with a list in there you can't use it any place (such as a dict key) where immutability is needed. Need to update my assumptions on 'immutability'...

Comment: @CorleyBrigman The tuple remains immutable... However, it contains mutable objects... There's a distinct difference... For instance `t = ([1],)` - you can't do `t[0] += [2]` as that in effect is trying to change the object the tuple contains, while if you do `t[0].extend([2])` then it's fine, as you've just mutated the underlying object and the tuple is still the same...

Comment: @JonClements - yeah, it makes sense. coming from C++, where you can 'confer' const status on objects on the fly (and objects aren't necessarily inherently mutable or immutable, it's how they, or the function header where it's used, are declared), it's a different model. just something for me to keep in mind.